# Using self created Weka Model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka

So I created a specific model in Weka and I want to use that in matlab.

IS there anyway to import a self created model to matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Java-Classes via a build in [bridge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html) to java, but please be aware that matlab runs it's own JRE, check the version and compatibility to WEKA.